# How to do deployment using alter script in ssas

Tags: ssas

Is any thing wrong if i create alter script on the entire database in analysis service in the development server SSMS and execute that script on the production  server SSMS instead of deploying through BIDS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you actually should never use BIDS to deploy to prod. BIDS will always overwrites the management settings(security and partition) of the target server.

the best option is to use the Deployment Wizard. It enables you to generate an incremental deployment script that updates the cube and dimension structures. Can customize how roles and partitions are handled. It uses as input files the XML output files generated by building the SSAS in BIDS and you can run on several modes:

- Silent Mode (/s): Runs the utility in silent mode and not display any dialog boxes.
- Answer file mode (/a): Do not deploy. Only modify the input files.
- Output mode (/o): No user interface is displayed. Generate the XMLA script that would be sent to the deployment targets. Deployment will not occur.

If you want a complete synchronization, you can use the "Synchronize Database Wizard". It pretty much clones a database. When the destination database already exists, it performs metadata synchronization and incremental data synchronization. When the destination database does not exist, a full deployment and data synchronization is done.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main disadvantage of scripting the whole database is that everything may be reprocessed. Also, if another team or team member is responsible for deploying the script it may be a lot harder to review and understand if everything is rebuilt with each update.

I work for Red Gate and we recently introduced a free tool called SSAS Compare to help manage  this scenario. It helps you to create a script containing just the changes you want to deploy