# Credentials to deploy SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am working on DW with SSAS cube. While development, my Cube is hosted on SQL SERVer 2008R2 on a development Server (Windows Server 2003).

Now, post to development phase I need to host the cube on test Server which would be on a remote location to which I do not have the access.

What are the possible ways I can host it on the server keeping in mind that If needed I need to re-deploy on server from BIDS Studio (when some bug arises).

What credentials I'll be needing (Will it do If I have a SQL sys rights or a windows account in that domain is a must)?

Thanks in advance!!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you shouldn't worry about it, taking into consideration of course, you have someone with access to the destination server.

You should never use BIDS to deploy your cube, it cant deal with partitions or security for example. Every deployment would overwrites these management settings of the target server.

Instead, you should use the Deployment Wizard to create your script and the you would send it to the person responsible for the deployment.

If you need more info about the deployment wizar, check my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742738/how-to-do-deployment-using-alter-script-in-ssas/10745152#10745152) post